# Flutter desktop windows get application path

Tags: flutter, dart

I am creating a Flutter Desktop application for windows and I am trying to retrieve the application directory where the exe is located. I tried to use path_provider but can only get the Documents directory. Any help I would appreciate lots.

Comment: What's the reason you want that location? If you are trying to load assets that are relative to your app's location, there are standard Flutter mechanisms for loading bundled assets.

Answer (score 18):

Use **`Platform.resolvedExecutable`**
(of `dart:io`).

I have tested it in Flutter/Windows and it works.
Strangely, `Platform.executable` returns `null` instead. I tell strangely because its type is String not nullable. This unexpected null value can cause crash or errors that are difficult to detect (but in the end Flutter desktop is not in the stable channel).

Answer (score 5):

```
String dir = Directory.current.path;
print(dir);
```

`Directory.current.path` (in the `dart:io` package) returns the current working directory of the project folder (when developing) or the executable directory when running from a release build.

Comment: Please consider adding additional comments as to _why_ this is the correct answer.  A code-only answer makes it less useful.

Comment: This answer is not correct; this returns the current working directory, which may or may not have anything to do with the location of the application.

Comment: The difference between this and `Platform.resolvedExecutable` (from `dart:io`) is that `Directory.current.path` defaults to root directory of the project folder when developing, but on release it defaults to the folder the executable is located (which is the runner folder when developing). 

Also `Platform.resolvedExecutable` is the absolute path to the .exe not the directory so you have to do some small work there. Both will get you there.

Answer (score 1):

Try is package: [path_provider](https://pub.dev/packages/path_provider/install)

> 1. set this code in pubspec.yaml

```
dependencies:
  path_provider: ^1.6.27 # get last Version From https://pub.dev/packages/path_provider/install
```

> 2. Code

```
Directory tempDir = await getTemporaryDirectory();
String tempPath = tempDir.path; //C:\Users\USER_NAME\AppData\Local\Temp

Directory appDocDir = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
String appDocPath = appDocDir.path; //C:\Users\USER_NAME\Documents
//Warning: on debug mode this code get location project but in release mode will get your location app correctly
String dir = Directory.current.path; // PATH_APP
```

Comment: `Directory.current` returns the current directory, which may or may not be the location of the application. For example, if my app is in `C:\my_app_folder` and I launch the app using the terminal from `C:`, executing `my_app_folder\my_app.exe`, then `Directory.current` returns `C:\`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue as you and solved in this way:

```
import 'package:path/path.dart';
 final directory = dirname(Platform.script.toFilePath());
```

it is going to give the location of your "run" file